# inserting elements using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a div in my div with id=main_area using JQuery append function now what i want to do is to add some elements like input fields and button in the div with id=this_one how can this be done?

```
$('#main_area').append('<div id="this_one">first div</div>');
```

Comment: What is the difference to what you already did, except for the id?

Comment: Just like you did with `#main_area`...

Answer (score 0):

The most performant way is to add everything at once:

```
var HTML = "<div id=\"this_one\"><input type=\"text\"> ... </div>";
 $('#main_area').append(HTML);
```

But you could of course just select the newly added element and then add extra stuff to it:

```
$('#main_area').append('<div id="this_one">first div</div>');
var HTML = "<input type=\"text\"> ...";
$("#this_one").append(HTML);
```

Comment: and if i want to delete one of the appended elements when i click on it how can this be done?

Comment: @asadrana you will need to listen for the click event on that particular element and then remove it `$("#main_area").on("click", "#idOfElementToRemoveOnClick", function(){ $(this).remove(); });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append()` like you're using. In this case is better to create the html output first and the append all at once to avoid excessive reflow. Manipulating DOM is slow.

```
var output = '<div><ul><li><label></label></li></ul></div>';
$('#main_area').append(output);
```

You can also use `appendTo()` which is probably better if you're adding more than one tag:

```
$('<div><ul><li><label></label></li></ul></div>').appendTo('#main_area');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reference it by `#this_one`:

```
$('#main_area').append('<div id="this_one">first div</div>');

var $this_one = $('#this_one');

$this_one.append('<p>Hello World!</p>');
$this_one.append('<p>Appended <input type="text"/></p>');
$this_one.append('<p>More fun stuff.</p>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYrTw/1/

Alternatively...

```
var $this_one = $('<div id="this_one">first div</div>');

$this_one.append('<p>Hello World!</p>');
$this_one.append('<p>Appended <input type="text"/></p>');
$this_one.append('<p>More fun stuff.</p>');

$('#main_area').append($this_one);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYrTw/2/

And if you're trying to remove elements that are clicked, you can use `$.on()` as long as you can select what you want to remove:

```
var $this_one = $('<div id="this_one">first div</div>');

var clickRemove = function(){
    $(this).remove();
};

$('#main_area').on('click', 'p', clickRemove);

$this_one.append('<p>Hello World!</p>');
$this_one.append('<p>Appended <input type="text"/></p>');
$this_one.append('<p>More fun stuff.</p>');

$('#main_area').append($this_one);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYrTw/4/

Another approach to adding the click -> remove handler:

```
var $main_area = $('#main_area'),
    $this_one = $('<div id="this_one">first div</div>');

function appendContent($j, html){
    var $html = $(html);

    var clickRemove = function(){
        $(this).remove();
    };

    $html.click(clickRemove);

    $j.append($html);
}

appendContent($this_one, '<p>Hello World!</p>');
appendContent($this_one, '<p>Appended <input type="text"/></p>');
appendContent($this_one, '<p>More fun stuff.</p>');

$main_area.append($this_one);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYrTw/5/